# POP3 Server Folder Structure Mirroring

Tags: pop3

Is there any way I can mirror my e-mail reader (Windows Live Mail) the folder structure I made on the webmail application (Outlook Web App)? Currently I have some three or four folders on the server but WLM doesn't recognize them and puts everything in the inbox.

Answer (score 1):

POP3 does not support folders; it only has the most basic set of features (list messages, get one message, delete one message). You will need to use IMAP.